# Why is my matrix not outputting the correct precision?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, precision, imread

I need to take a very large matrix that is generated by using the function `imread()`. This turns an image (mine is a jpg file; 691x763) into a matrix.

I need to divide each element in the matrix by 255 and show each element with at least 3 decimal places.

**What I've tried:**

`output_precision(4)` but it didn't work for the elements inside the matrix.

`format long e` but the values inside the matrix were still unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `im2double` http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/im2double.html which does the scaling to 0..1 for you independently of the input format which might be uint, uint16, int16 and so on.

Comment: Is there any difference between using `im2double` and the method shown in the other answer?

Comment: As I already wrote in my answer, im2double will work independetly of the input format. For example if the input image is uint16 it will divide through 65535. UTSL! https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/image/ci/default/tree/inst/imcast.m https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/image/ci/default/tree/src/im2double.m.in

Comment: @whatwhatwhat and since the function has been moved to Octave core, see the [source there](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/9810e483b42f/scripts/image/im2double.m) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `imread()` gave you a matrix of `uint8`. Try this instead:

```
I = imread('image.jpg'); %// your image
A = double(I)/255; %//convert matrix to double before dividing it by 255
```